# Azure integration account (Maps - XSLT) - Merge 2 different XMLs into single xml with Logic Apps

Tags: xml, azure, xslt, transformation, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic Apps, I have 2 **different** xml files Parent.xml & Children.xml in JSON format.

**Requirement -** *I need to create merge these 2 file into single Family.xml file using XSLT stored in Integration Account.*

**Help required in creating XSLT with in-built C# code for custom code logic. This XSLT is required to be placed in maps of Azure Integration Account. **

**Below are the samples** :-

**Parent.xml**

```
    <ParentRoot>
     <ParentName>
      <Father>
        <FirstName>FFirstName</FirstName>
        <LastName>FLastName</LastName>
        <Age>35</Age>
      </Father>
      <Mother>
        <FirstName>MFirstName</FirstName>
        <LastName>MLastName</LastName>
        <Age>33</Age>
      </Mother>
     </ParentName>            
    </ParentRoot>
```

**Children.xml**

```
<ChildrenRoot>
<Child>
    <FirstName>Child1FirstName</FirstName>
    <LastName>Child1LastName</LastName>
    <Age>14</Age>
</Child>
<Child>
    <FirstName>Child2FirstName</FirstName>
    <LastName>Child2LastName</LastName>
    <Age>10</Age>
</Child>
</ChildrenRoot>
```

**Family.xml**

```
<FamilyRoot>
  <ParentName>
          <Father>
            <FirstName>FFirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>FLastName</LastName>
            <Age>35</Age>
          </Father>
          <Mother>
            <FirstName>MFirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>MLastName</LastName>
            <Age>33</Age>
          </Mother>
  </ParentName>
<TotalChildren>2</TotalChildren>
<ChildrenCollection>
    <Child>
        <FirstName>Child1FirstName</FirstName>
        <LastName>Child1LastName</LastName>
        <Age>14</Age>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <FirstName>Child2FirstName</FirstName>
        <LastName>Child2LastName</LastName>
        <Age>10</Age>             
    </Child>
</ChildrenCollection>     
</FamilyRoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you'd better merge the two xml resources to one xml as the resource in logic app, shown as below:

```
<root>
    <ParentRoot>
         <ParentName>
              <Father>
                <FirstName>FFirstName</FirstName>
                <LastName>FLastName</LastName>
                <Age>35</Age>
              </Father>
              <Mother>
                <FirstName>MFirstName</FirstName>
                <LastName>MLastName</LastName>
                <Age>33</Age>
              </Mother>
         </ParentName>            
    </ParentRoot>

    <ChildrenRoot>
        <Child>
            <FirstName>Child1FirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>Child1LastName</LastName>
            <Age>14</Age>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <FirstName>Child2FirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>Child2LastName</LastName>
            <Age>10</Age>
        </Child>
    </ChildrenRoot>
</root>
```

Then I write a xsl code to transform the xml for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="FamilyRoot">
            <xsl:element name="ParentName">
                <xsl:element name="Father">
                    <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/FirstName" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="LastName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/LastName" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Age">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/Age" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Mother">
                    <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/FirstName" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="LastName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/LastName" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Age">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/ParentRoot/ParentName/Father/Age" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="TotalChildren">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="count(//Child)"/>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="ChildrenCollection">
                <xsl:for-each select="root/ChildrenRoot/Child">
                    <xsl:element name="Child">
                        <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="LastName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="LastName" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Age">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Age" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After that, we can upload the xsl code above to integration account as a map and use "[Transform XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform)" action in logic app to transform the xml resource.

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: Thanks for responding on Transformation part. I am also looking for help  in how can I include custom C#  fucntions  with XSLT and call then with in the xsl Tags. I have many other additional tags in the  sample examples for which I need to calculations based on some logic.

Comment: @Varun05, yes I think solve it by c# function is a better solution. It is not easy for us to do it in logic app.

Comment: Mainly I need to understand how to call methods of C# assembly uploaded in assemblies section of Azure Integration Account from the XSLT. This XSLT is also placed wthin  Maps section of Azure Integration Account